# How to compare ISO8601 type dates in postgres with java?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am creating a spring boot project where I am storing date under my jpa entity class and using the `@CreatedDate` annotation I am storing ISO type date in postgres.Now I want to filter the date based on `date_before` and `date_after` both of them given in query params in the request.

How can I do it in postgres query?

My JPA class:

```
@Entity
public class Model{

String name;
@CreatedDate
Date date;
}
```

Now I get my request with both `date_before` and `date_after` fields which are both in ISO format.How do I write a query that does the filter operation for me?

Comment: Never use either of the terrible `Date` classes. Supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310, specifically `LocalDate` and `Instant`.